# How do I force an update in a configuration activity?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm writing a widget with a configuration activity which calls the following method when its `OK` button is clicked:

```
private void ok()
{
    // ...Do Widget Configuration...

    // Force an update
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(widget_id, views);

    // Return the expected result
    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widget_id);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);

    finish();
}
```

This is almost verbatim from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring).  `widget_id` holds the widget ID that was dug up during the activity's `onCreate()`.

When I place an instance of the widget on the home screen, I've verified that I get the expected sequence of events:

- `onReceive()` gets an `ACTION_APPWIDGET_ENABLED` if it's the first one.
- `onUpdate()` gets called (in which I detect that the widget isn't configured and draw something as a default action).
- The configuration activity appears.
- When I press `OK`, the `ok()` method above gets called.

The method gets all the way through to the `finish()` and the configuration activity goes away, but there's no call to `onUpdate()` or `onReceive()` after this point.  (The widget itself has no `updatePeriodMillis`.)  I end up with a widget on the screen that has the results of my default action but never gets updated.

If I set the widget up without a configuration activity, it gets updated when created and everything works as expected (just without the configured bits).

Am I missing something in the way I force an update?

Thanks!

Comment: this is a known bug in android: onUpdate should only be called once you've returned from your config activity. I have the exact same problem. Hopefully 3.2 will solve it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This turned out to work:

```
new MyWidgetProviderClass()
  .onUpdate(this,
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this),
            new int[] { widget_id }
   );
```

Comment: As horrible as this is, that's what I also ended up doing. I keep a static reference to my AppWidgetProvider around on which I call onUpdate(). It's sad that that's currently the only way.

Comment: I also faced this issue. But how can we pass configuration values to `AppWidgetProvider onUpdate method` ?

Comment: @256 : you can either save the info in th DB or use SharedPreferences using the widgetId to keep the infos distinct

Comment: That worked for me. Spent about a day on this